# Why does sqrt(xt) not work properly? ValueError: math domain error

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I want to make a program that says what are the solutions to  n   in the function  2^n  -15 = xt  where n is a positive integer and xt is a square number. But this doesn't work:

```
from math import sqrt
n = 0
def is_square(x):
    answer = sqrt(x)
    return answer.is_integer()

while True:
    n += 1
    xt = 2 ^ n - 15
    if is_square(xt):
        print(xt)
```

The error says this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/NemPl/Desktop/Python/Python programi/M/P #1.py", line 9, in <module>
    if is_square(xt):
  File "C:/Users/NemPl/Desktop/Python/Python programi/M/P #1.py", line 4, in is_square
    answer = sqrt(x)
ValueError: math domain error
```

Comment: I doubt the `2^n` is really what you want

Comment: (1) The caret `^` does not calculate powers but bitwise XOR. To calculate powers use `**`. (2) You created an endless loop. Python will go on until it encounters an error. In your case you hit one early, when `2^n-15` became negative right away. To fix that, define a criterion to end the loop: `if n > 1000: break`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer**: you aim to calculate the square root of a **negative number**.

If we add a `print(xt)` statement to the program:

```
while True:
    n += 1
    xt = 2 ^ n - 15
    print(xt)
    if is_square(xt):
        print(xt)
```

We see that the first element that is queried, is:

```
-16
```

Although there are *complex* numbers that represent square roots of negative numbers, `math.sqrt(..)` works on floating points, so a subset of "*reals*". Now for reals, the square root of a negative number is *not* defined.

Finally not that `^` does **not calculate the power**, one can calculate the power by using `2 ** n` (or `1 << n` in this case). The caret **`^` is a bitwise or**.

Answer (score 5):

This error could happen when your argument to `sqrt` is a negative number.

The `math.sqrt` function is not able to calculate the square of a negative numbers.

You can use the `cmath` lib for negative number:

```
import cmath
print (cmath.sqrt(-2))
>>> 1.4142135623730951j
```

Answer (score 2):

`math.sqrt` apparently does not like negative numbers which would lead to a complex result. From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html):

> These functions cannot be used with complex numbers; use the functions of the same name from the cmath module if you require support for complex numbers. The distinction between functions which support complex numbers and those which don’t is made since most users do not want to learn quite as much mathematics as required to understand complex numbers. Receiving an exception instead of a complex result allows earlier detection of the unexpected complex number used as a parameter, so that the programmer can determine how and why it was generated in the first place.

Use `cmath.sqrt()` from [cmath](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmath.html) if you need complex results as well.